# Wait for Workflow to Complete before Redirecting

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I need to redirect users to a new page once a workflow is complete. This is required because I am redirecting users to a Display Form once the New Form data is entered, instead of returning them to the All Items view. I need the workflow to complete, as it updates field values and security.

Currently, I am sending them to a redirect page from the New Form that has a JavaScript function to check if the a column for Workflow status has changed to true. To loop and check, I am just calling the same function again... which is very very bad practice! Using jQuery, how could I check to see if the SharePoint Workflow completes? My initial code crack is as follows:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js", 'SP.ClientContext', redirectNewItem);

function redirectNewItem() {

// REST call to get the current user
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: "/sites/mysite/_api/web/currentUser",
        type: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
        success: function (user) {

            //Get the user ID
            var userID = user.d.Id;

            // REST call to pass in the current user to get the most recent item created by the user. This is to ensure that the redirect goes to the item they just created after the workflow setting field values and security has completed.
            $.ajax({
                async: false,
                url: "/sites/mysite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('mylist')/items?$filter=AuthorId eq " + userID + "&$top=1&$orderby=Created desc",
                type: "GET",
                headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
                success: function (data) {

                    //Get the user ID
                    $.each(data.d.results, function (index, value) {
                        var itemID = value.Id;

                        var redirectURL = "/sites/mysite/Lists/mylist/DispForm.aspx?ID=" + itemID

                        if (value.WorkflowComplete == "True") {
                            // Redirect to display form with correct ID

                            window.location.replace(redirectURL);
                        }
                        redirectNewItem();
                    });

                },
                error: function (data) {
                    //output error HERE
                    alert(data.statusText);
                }
            });
        },
        error: function (user) {
            //output error HERE
            alert(data.statusText);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have it working by changing the function call to include a timeout of 5 seconds. This loops until the conditional statement is true. I also updated my code to get the userID from the page context instead of using a REST call:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js", 'SP.ClientContext', redirectNewItem);

function redirectNewItem() {

//Get the user ID
var userID = _spPageContextInfo.userId;

// REST call to pass in the current user to get the most recent item created by the user. This is to ensure that the redirect goes to the item they just created after the workflow setting field values and security has completed.
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    url: "/sites/mysite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('mylist')/items?$filter=AuthorId eq " + userID + "&$top=1&$orderby=Created desc",
    type: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
    success: function (data) {

        //Get the user ID
        $.each(data.d.results, function (index, value) {
            var itemID = value.Id;

            var redirectURL = "/sites/mysite/Lists/mysite/DispForm.aspx?ID=" + itemID

            if (value.WorkflowComplete == "True") {
                // Redirect to display form with correct ID

                window.location.replace(redirectURL);
            }
            setTimeout(redirectNewItem, 5000);
        });

    },
    error: function (data) {
        //output error HERE
        alert(data.statusText);
    }
});
```

}